# Device not found error in Vagrant with Chef-Solo while testing cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I have created some cookbooks in a repository which are executed in instances in AWS.  I manually create an EBS volume in AWS at location `dev/xvdb` and then mount it using the following chef code:

```
mount "mount encrypted EBS volume at opt directory for app deployment" do
  action [:mount, :enable]
  device "/dev/xvdb"
  fstype "ext3"
  mount_point "/opt"
end
```

Now, in an effort to test the cookbooks locally, I have configured a vagrant box and trying to run the cookbook that contains the above code in it.  I have the following Vagrant configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
      chef.data_bags_path = "databags"
      chef.environments_path = "environments"
      chef.environment = "dev"
      chef.roles_path = "roles"
      chef.add_role("webapp")
  end
end
```

But as the Vagrant box does not have a `/dev/xvdb` folder path, it fails with:

> ==> default: Chef::Exceptions::Mount
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default: -----------------------
>   ==> default:
>   ==> default: Device /dev/xvdb does not exist

How can I enable testing this locally on my vagrant box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like `only_if { node['ec2'] }` so it only converges that resource on actual EC2 machines. You can also use stuff from `node['cloud']` or similar to check, or if you wanted to make it completely generic somehow, `only_if { ::File.exist?('/dev/xvdb') }`.